# How to filter data in Kibana query language using regex

Tags: regex, kibana

I have one field in Kibana Discover having below values -

```
D_00122 - A - 14
D_00133A - 15
D_00145 - 18
D_00167 - B - 18
D_00182A - 19
D_00121 - A - 13
D_0011 - 18
```

I want to right a KQL to select only values having format below -

- Start with 'D_' then numbers(no character after numbers).
- one space
- hyphen
- one space
- Then numbers

Final output -

```
D_00145 - 18
D_0011 - 18
```

I tried below query but it's not working -

```
data_no.keyword : D_* AND NOT data_no.keyword : 'D_*A - *'
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex : "D_\d+ - \d+" will catch only the two line you want to catch.

"D_" matches the characters "D_" literally (case sensitive)

"\d" matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

"+" matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

" - " matches the characters " - " literally (case sensitive)

see : https://regex101.com/r/SJQ6ou/1

and use this website to learn and test regex

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately it's not working in KQL. Getting error - 'Expected AND, OR, end of input, whitespace but "\" found'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [an ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to check this condition and create a new field for that. Here is how you can do it:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00122 - A - 14" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00133A - 15" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00145 - 18" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00167 - B - 18" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "5" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00182A - 19" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "6" } }
{ "data_no": "D_00121 - A - 13" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_sample_index", "_id" : "7" } }
{ "data_no": "D_0011 - 18" }
```

---

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/check_dash
{
  "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "data_no",
          "patterns": [
            "%{NOTSPACE:data1} - %{NOTSPACE:data2} - %{NOTSPACE:data3}",
            "%{NOTSPACE:data1} - %{NOTSPACE:data2}"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "if": "ctx.data3 == null",
          "field": "number_after_dash",
          "value": true
        }
      },
      {
        "remove": {
          "field": ["data1", "data2", "data3"],
          "ignore_failure": true
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

---

```
POST my_sample_index/_update_by_query?pipeline=check_dash
GET my_sample_index/_search
```

[image]

### The result from Kibana Discover:

[image]